# How can I update ViewPager fragment data?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hello anyone i have working on a reading application and I have build up a view pager contain three fragment, **bookFragment**, **chapterFragment** and **verseFragment**

I want to update the **chapterFragment** and **verseFragment** when user selected one book item, but the fragment UI still not exit, so I can't do refreshUI in OnPagerSelected.

It any way to do this?

follow is my adapter:

```
private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private int[] title = {R.string.label_book, R.string.label_chapter, R.string.label_verse};

    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return bookFragment = new SelectionBookFragment();

            case 1:
                return chapterFragment = new SelectionChapterFragment();

            case 2:
                return verseFragment = new SelectionVerseFragment();
        }
        return new Fragment();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return getResources().getString(title[position]);
    }
}
```

and the fragment UI is null when I do this:

```
Fragment fragment = screenSlidePagerAdapter.getItem(CHOOSER_CHAPTER);
fragment.refreshUI() <-- null
```

Big Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the fragment doesn't exist, the method `onCreateView()` will be called when showing up. You can set book's data in here.
If the fragment exist, you can call `refreshUI()`.
I think you only need to check `fragment != null` when call `refreshUI()`.

Comment: Added the null checking, and also modified the getItem to **return bookFragment == null? bookFragment = new SelectionBookFragment() : bookFragment;** Is work now, thanks~

Answer (score 0):

A simple and dirty way would be to force the ViewPager to create all the Fragment instances and keep them, by calling

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
```

Another way is to save the selected value in SharedPreferences and then retrieve the value when the Page is shown.

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(SELECTED_BOOK, 0);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
  editor.putInt("selectedBook", 3);
```